# How to create a black background and merge it with a image file with imagick?

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, imagick

I'm uploading an image from my mobile app to the server. I need to add two black bars on the top and bottom of the image. So what i tried is creating a black rectangle size of 2400x1200px and resize the uploaded image to 2400x930px and lay it on top of the black background.

```
 $key = "video";
 $document['video'] = $this->uploadfile($key);
 $key = "thumbnail";
 $document['thumbnail'] = $this->uploadfile($key);
 $msg="panoramic image uploaded!";

 $originalImagePath = "http://..../1501157655mainImage.png";
 //$originalImagePath .= $document['video'];
 $originalImage = new Imagick($originalImagePath);

 $background = new Imagick();
 $pixel = new ImagickPixel('#000000');
 $background->newImage(2400, 1200, $pixel);

 $originalImage->resizeImage(2370, 930)

 $finalImage = $background->compositeimage($originalImage, Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPY, 1200, 600);

 $document['new_video'] = $this->uploadfile($finalImage);
```

But it does not work. it fails at the 'new Imagick' i believe. I'm totally new to php. (Only couple of days). This code is written in a class. I have imported the imagemagick library in the construct method with the line

```
$this->load->library('Image_magician');
```

Copied the Image_magician.php file in the libraries folder. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Exactly *what error* does it give?

Comment: Sounds like the imagick module is not installed on the system.

Comment: `$originalImagePath = "http://..../1501157655mainImage.png";` is not image path it is URL. You do need path and it should be something like `FCPATH.'1501157655mainImage.png'`.

Comment: Why not try something simple first to prove Imagick is working with a couple of static files? Also your code could be simplified by using http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.extentimage.php